# Using PendingIntent to update the status of an fail sent message

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-contentprovider, android-pendingintent

After a user sends an SMS if it is not sent for any reason would update the [STATUS column](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#STATUS).

Note: We are using the provider "content://sms/" to access the SMS repository.

### SMS Sender class

```
**Constructor**
public SmsMessageSender(MessageRepository messageRepository, ThreadRepository threadRepository, Context context)
{
    this(messageRepository, threadRepository);
    this.sentIntent = new Intent(SmsMessageSender.SENT);
    this.sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, this.sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Override
public void sendMessage(String recipient, String content) {

    long threadId = threadRepository.getOrCreateThreadForRecipients(recipient);
    ArrayList<String> messageParts = generateMessages(content);

    sentIntent.putExtra("threadId", threadId);


    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(recipient, null, messageParts,
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sentPI)), null);

    Uri uri = messageRepository.insert(new Message(0, recipient, content, new Date(), null, 
        MessageStatus.Sent, threadId, Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.STATUS_NONE));
    sentIntent.putExtra("messageUri", uri.toString());
}
```

### Activity

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            if (getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                long threadId = arg1.getLongExtra("threadId", -1);
                // TODO: Update SMS message with status fail
            } else {
                // TODO: Update SMS message with status success
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SmsMessageSender.SENT));
}
```

On BroadcastReceiver in `onReceive` method on my activity, the `long threadId = arg1.getLongExtra("threadId", -1);` always returns -1. (the value put in Extra is different from -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the extra to `sentIntent` too late. You need to do this **before you generate the `PendingIntent`** by calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.